# Is it possible to get a resized version of an image stored on Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-storage, expo

I'm using GCS to store my user's images in our react-native app. I need a small version of images so I can implement progressive loading. Is there any way to get a resized image from the GCS url or using any other method?

I'd like to avoid having multiple instances of the same image in our storage.

I know you can do something like:

http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/93uhV8K2yHkRuD63KJxlTi7SxjHS8my2emuHmGLZxEmX99_XAjTN3c_2zmKVb3XQ5d8FEkwtgbGjyYpaDQg=s250

with google photos, where the =sXX at the end (xx being any number between 0 and ~2500) is the size that returned image will be.

is it possible to do something similar using GCS?

this is what a url to an image looks like with respect to our app:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/appName.appspot.com/1513912717946-Image_1513912675892.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

You need App Engine to generate those URLs, and this is only available in the standard environment.

Relevant docs are: [Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/images/#get-serving-url), [Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/images/#get-serving-url), [PHP](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/images), and [Go](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/images/reference#ServingURL).

The API allows you to generate (and delete) those URLs. The generated URLs support the `=sXX` parameter. `XX` is an integer from 0–2560 representing the length, in pixels, of the image's longest side. It also supports cropping the image into a square with `=sXX-c`.

---

Elaborating: [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) is Google's [PaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service) offering. You can read more about the standard and flexible environments [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments).

Comment: Could u elaborate on what you mean by "the standard environment" please?

Comment: anything for node.js?